# Find model after initializing collection returns empty array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

In my app I have profile collection where user can create more profiles. After creating profile function should return current list of profiles. It works but not at the first time. When user register and a collection of profiles isn't intialized yet it returns empty array. Creating second profile returns array with both profiles. How can I work around this? Create all collections after register or can I change something in my add profile function?

```js
// Adding profile
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  let profile = new Profile({
    name: req.body.name,
    picture: req.body.picture,
  });
  profile.save();
  try {
    profile = await Profile.find();
    console.log(profile);
    res.status(200).json({ success: "Profile added", profiles: profile });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

Comment: `profile.save()` is an asynchronous method, you should `await` until completion of task

Comment: @ram12393 Okay, that works. But why it worked without await after first init? I mean it returned both profiles, not only all previous.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your app remove unnecessary Profile.find() and return only inserted profile

```js
// Adding profile
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let profile = new Profile({
      name: req.body.name,
      picture: req.body.picture,
    });
    // save document and return updated doc
    const saved = await profile.save();
    // convert Document into plain js object to prevent sending db meta information
    res.status(200).json({ success: "Profile added", profile: saved.toObject() });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});

// Getting Profiles

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.status(200).json({ profiles: await Profile.find() });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```